# Question is on hold

Tags: discussion

Gentlemen!

Those who put [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125228/ubuntu-18-10-radius-server-login-problem-updated) on hold. Did you try to understand what was going on there? I have been struggling with the problem for about 3 weeks. Plenty comments left. I am at the same point. Does it worth to go on? I am not suppose to dig through tons of manuals, searching the net.

I should install UBUNTU and HAVE BASIC THINGS running.

If this is not a case here, then I am on the wrong road.

I needed UBUNTU to save internet traffic, but how much I have already spent, none of WINDOWS 10 would do.

Are you able to help? If NO - say it, but do not put ON HOLD.

You may even BAN me - I do not care - I will switch to DEBIAN - this OS works.
Yes, it does not look so pretty, but operational.

If The Community has the power to control users here, It Must have enough knowledge as well. Power without knowledge and understanding is destructive

**To Pilot6, personally.

Please read the post to the end and tell me WHERE the problem is 'AT ALL'.**

Comment: Please calm down, ranting will not help you. Also, no one wants to ban you. I didn't know the Q before, but reading it and especially the comments below it feels like it is indeed unclear what you're asking, otherwise there wouldn't be the need of so many comments. Problem here is that comments purpose is not to be like a chat, that is why people tell you to improve your question. I'm sure if you edit your question and clarify it, it will be reopened, as it seems a legit question to me.

Comment: Please refrain from these rapid edits of your posts, it makes it noisy and bumps it every time you edit; I have activated a lock on this post to prevent additional edits, since this issue is now also resolved, and there's no need to apply additional edits to this post.

Answer (score 11):

I suspect the question was put on hold by the community due to the scarcity of information that the initial post had.

You have correctly now added much more info to it - so thanks!

Keep on editing as and when clarifications to comments are made.  Hopefully the community can help with the extra info added.

As such I have hit the reopen button for you.

Comment: You need to use ubuntu-bug from Ubuntu itself - this is to ensure all relevant information about your system is uploaded at the same time.

Comment: @fossfreedom, `ubuntu-bug` says `package netplan is not installed `on UBUNTU 18.10. I tried `ubuntu-bug netplan.io` - there is an error saying that `it is not original UBNTU`. How is it possible, when OS is just installed from ISO, downloaded from UBUNTU.com. Can you suggest something else? Shell I use `ubuntu-bug NetworkManager` instead? Another question is how do I login with LAUNCHPAD, if at the moment of the report I will not have internet connection due to this bug?

Comment: @Igor you have two questions here that should be asked via the main site - not in comments.  "How do I identify a valid package name for ubuntu-bug?" and "How do I use ubuntu-bug with no internet access?"